# Pass Module into Require.js require.config

Tags: javascript, requirejs

Is it possible to pass in a module to require.config? I have a module that is created in the DOM prior to require.config that contains server-side configuration data and I'd like to be able to have access to that inside of my require.config file. Here is an example of what I'm trying to do.

```
    define("config", 
    [],
    function() {
        var Config = {};   
        Config.locale = '{$locale}';
        Config.version = '{$version}';
        return Config;
    });
```

Then I'd like to be able to pass the Config module into require.config as.

```
require.config({

  paths: {
    link1: "//url/" + Config.version + "/data.js",
    link2: "//url/" + Config.version + "/data.js",
    link3: "//url/" + Config.version + "/data.js"
},
```

As always, any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried your method? Although I haven't, I'm pretty sure config is not treated as a module.

You could take advantage of defining require as an object before the library is loaded.

```
<script>
    var require = (function(){

        // Do your setup stuff here

        // Now return the config object
        return {
            baseUrl: 'test/path/'
            paths: {
                // etc
            }
        }

    })()
</script>
<script src="require.js"></script>
```